# Passing sgm files in which the filenames contain spaces and comma using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have some of the sgm files in which the filename contains spaces and commas. So how can i send all the sgm files line by line to the conversion program on command prompt ?

1. How to send list of SGM files in the directory that have spaces and commas in the filename ?
2. How to ignore those spaces and commas as shown below:

**Sample SGM Files :**

```
Medco Health Solutions, Inc.  No Action, Interpretive and or Exemptive Letter of August 13, 2002.sgm

MP Environmental Funding LLC, PE Environmental Funding LLC  No Action, Interpretive and or Exemptive Letter of September 19, 2007.sgm

Nationwide Financial Services, Inc. and Provident Mutual Life Insurance Company  No Action, Interpretive and or Exemptive Letter of August 9, 2002.sgm
```

**My Code of running:**

```
c:\Work> table2srt.bat "Medco Health Solutions, Inc.  No Action, Interpretive and or Exemptive Letter of August 13, 2002.sgm"
```

**Output :**

```
Error cannot open Medco.tables
```

Any help for this is highly appreciated !!!

**Batch Code:(table2srt.bat)**

```
@echo off

rem **************************************************
rem    Check USAGE
rem **************************************************
if "%1" == ""  GOTO USAGE

set rat=%4
if "%4" == "" set rat=1.75

set wid=%5
if "%5" == "" set wid=78

set maxw=%6
if "%6" == "" set maxw=100


echo.
echo ***********************************************************
echo Get all the tables from the file %1.sgm                   
echo ***********************************************************
echo.
echo Program     : %VPISRC%\srt_tables.pl
echo Input File  : %1.sgm
echo Output File : %1.tables
%OMNIDIR%\Perl\bin\perl.exe srt_tables.pl %1.sgm


for %%F in (%1.tables) do (
if %%~zF equ 0 goto NOTABLE
)


echo.
echo *****************************************************
echo Conversion of tables completed successfully         
echo ***************************************************** 
echo.
echo *****************************
echo Convert SGML Table to Perl
echo *****************************
echo   Program        : %VPISRC%\table2srt.om5
echo   DTD            : %VPIDTD%\tabledoc.dtd
echo   Input File     : %1.tables
echo   Ratio          : %rat%
echo   Ideal Width    : %wid%
echo   Maximum Width  : %maxw%
echo   Output File    : %1.prl

echo.

echo %VPIDTD%\decl.sgm              > %1.arg
echo %VPIDTD%\tabledoc.dtd          >> %1.arg
echo %1.tables                          >> %1.arg
echo -s %VPISRC%\table2srt.om5          >> %1.arg
echo -of %1.prl                     >> %1.arg
echo -d ratio %rat%                 >> %1.arg
echo -d max-width %maxw%            >> %1.arg
echo -d ideal-width %wid%           >> %1.arg
echo -d FN %1                       >> %1.arg
echo -l %VPIDTD%/                   >> %1.arg
echo -alog %1.log                   >> %1.arg
echo -i %VPINCLD%\          >> %1.arg

%OMNIDIR%\omnimark -f %1.arg

if errorlevel 4 goto REPORT


rem *********************************************************
rem    Run the Perl script
rem *********************************************************
:PERL
echo.
echo Perform Perl Script....
echo   Input File  : %1.prl
echo   Output File : %1.srt
echo.

%OMNIDIR%\Perl\bin\perl %1.prl > %1.srt

if errorlevel 1 goto BUMMER



echo.
echo Done.
echo.

rem *********************************************************
rem    Merge SRT
rem *********************************************************
echo.
echo Merge SRT Table back in
echo   Program        : %VPISRC%\mrgsrt.om5
echo   Input File     : %1.sgm
echo   SRT File       : %1.srt
echo   Output File    : %1.fnl
echo   Log File       : %1.log
echo.

echo %1.sgm                      > %1.arg
echo -s %VPISRC%\mrgsrt.om5    >> %1.arg
echo -of %1.fnl                >> %1.arg
echo -d FN %1                  >> %1.arg
echo -log %1.log               >> %1.arg
echo -i %VPINCLD%\      >> %1.arg

%OMNIDIR%\omnimark -f %1.arg

if errorlevel 1 goto BUMMER


echo.
echo Done.
echo.


rem *******************************************
rem  SRT Cleanup 
rem *******************************************
echo Program     : %VPISRC%\srt_cleanup.pl
echo Input File  : %1.fnl
echo Output File : %1.sgm
%OMNIDIR%\Perl\bin\perl.exe srt_cleanup.pl %1.fnl

echo.
echo *****************************************************
echo Conversion of table to srt completed successfully   
echo *****************************************************

echo.
echo *****************************************************
echo  Secnal Conversion Completed with final
echo  output file as %1.sgm  
echo *****************************************************

if exist %1.srt del %1.srt
if exist %1.arg del %1.arg
if exist %1.err del %1.err
if exist %1.prl del %1.prl
if exist %1.log del %1.log
if exist %1.tables del %1.tables
if exist %1.fnl del %1.fnl
goto DONE



:NOTABLE
echo *************************************************************
echo No Tables exists in this file  %1.sgm     
echo *************************************************************
echo.
echo *****************************************************
echo  Secnal Conversion Completed with final
echo  output file as %1.sgm  
echo *****************************************************
goto DONE 

:BUMMER
echo Bummer....
echo Check %1.log
echo.
goto DONE

:REPORT
echo.
echo Bummer. Unexpected Conversion Errors.
echo Check %1.err
echo.
goto DONE

::USAGE
echo.
echo USAGE is TABL2SRT (FILENAME) (SGM)
echo    Optional: (RATIO) (IDEAL WIDTH) (MAXIMIM WIDTH)
echo.
goto DONE

:DONE
set rat=
set wid=
set maxw=
```

Comment: The problem is not the command line as you are passing the file name properly quoted, but the batch file does not handle it correctly. If you can, post the batch file code.

Comment: @MC ND : I have put my batch code. Can you have a look and let me know where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one extract from the code. The same problem happens in all the file

```
%OMNIDIR%\Perl\bin\perl.exe srt_tables.pl %1.sgm


for %%F in (%1.tables) do (
if %%~zF equ 0 goto NOTABLE
)
```

`%1` contains a quoted file name with extension, so what the parser interprets is

```
c:\somewhere\Perl\bin\perl.exe srt_tables.pl "Medco Health .... 2002.sgm".sgm

for %%F in ("Medco Health .... 2001.sgm".tables) do (
if %%~zF equ 0 goto NOTABLE
)
```

It should be something like

```
"%OMNIDIR%\Perl\bin\perl.exe" srt_tables.pl "%~1"
```

passing the full file name, without quotes (from here the `%~1` instead of `%1`) and quoted again (just in case maybe you initially forgot the quotes).

Will the perl program property generate the output file? Supossing it will correctly work,  then the next code should be

```
for %%F in ("%~n1.tables") do (
    if %%~zF equ 0 goto NOTABLE
)
```

As it seems (from your code) that the perl programs generates a file with the same name but with the extension replaced with `.tables`, instead of using `%~1` that will retrieve the name with extension, `%~n1` is used, retrieving only the file name. And, of course, all quoted as spaces are present.

Lines as

```
echo %VPIDTD%\decl.sgm              > %1.arg
```

Should be

```
echo %VPIDTD%\decl.sgm              > "%~n1.arg"
```

Equivalent changes are needed in all the batch file.

When all the changes are made, for the command line call to process all the files

```
for %a in (*.sgm) do table2srt.bat "%a"
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to apply in this particular case, but if the original `%1` _were_ to contain a path (instead of just a file in the current directory), you can use `%~dpn1` to extract the drive, path and filename.

Comment: @MC ND: I have made some changes apart from your changes and its working fine. Thank you !!  Truly Awesome :)